# How can I tell which revision of a file I checked out?

Tags: tfs

I checked out a binary file in TFS - it's a source code file used by a proprietary system.
When I come to check it in I discover someone else has since committed a change. Since it's a binary file I cannot do a diff but worse, I can't even remember when I checked the file out e.g. which revision of the file I'm working on, to see how many commits I need to figure out.

How can I find this out?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use TFVC or Git version control? Was your workspace new created when you checked out the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [tf status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/status-command?view=vsts) command with `/format:detailed` to see whether you can get the information you want:

```
tf stat itemspec /format:detailed
```